# How can I dynamically use the Google Maps API to list reviews for a location(s)?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using JSON to populate any one / several business locations on a website. The JSON for each location includes the geo-coordinates (lat/lng), and the Google Place Id for that location.

On any given page in my website, I may wish to list 1, or several locations using the JSON. What I am after is dynamically grabbing the 5 reviews and the rating for that location.

As it is right now,  the code below works, but only with a callback in the  tag. Basically, what I am after, is to have a function that takes 3 parameters, a placeId, and the lat and longitude.

Also, do I have to have an element named "map" when in fact I am not using a map on the page, I just want the 5 reviews.

```
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=places" async defer></script>
<script>
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: 41.14791780, lng: -81.47000470},
    zoom: 9
  });

  var request = {
    placeId: 'ChIJc2HE96Oj6IgR9YJ5UNAWMX8',
    fields: ['name', 'rating', 'reviews']
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var reviews = place.reviews;
      console.log(place.reviews)
      // Process and display the reviews on your web page as desired
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

I tried removing the callback in the script source, and creating a function, but to no success.

Comment: Please see [ask].  Only ask one question in a question.  For the question: "do I have to have an element named 'map'"? See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlacesService.constructor)  **PlacesService(attrContainer)**, Parameters: 
attrContainer:  HTMLDivElement|Map, Creates a new instance of the PlacesService that renders attributions in the specified container.

Comment: JSON is NOT a JavaScript object but a specially formatted string that can be parsed into a JavaScript object

Answer (score -1):

After some thought, I found the answer:

```
locations.forEach(function(l) {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapX'), {
center: {lat: 41.14791780, lng: -81.47000470},
zoom: 9
});
var request = {
placeId: l.placeId,
fields: ['rating', 'reviews', 'user_ratings_total']
};
var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
var reviews = place.reviews;
console.log(place.rating + ' ' + place.user_ratings_total)
// Process and display the reviews on your web page as desired
}
});
})
```

Comment: this does not seem like the optimum way to approach this problem. Creating multiple map objects within the `forEach` loop could become an expensive operation in more ways than one. (Google charge per map invocation/instantiation, amongst other things, so the fewer map loads the better!)

Comment: + there was a comment on your question that points to the documentation which states the container doesn't need to be a map instance.